# Support for 192kHz audio in Android

Tags: android, audio

is there any way to support 192kHz audio in AudioTrack in Android? I know that android officially supports only sampling up to 44100 Hz, but there are devices that allegedly can play audio with 192kHz sampling like LG G2, Samsung G Note 3 and few others. But event on these devices I can't set sample rate higher than 96000Hz. 
In AudioTrack sources there is this line:

```
/** Maximum value for sample rate */
private static final int SAMPLE_RATE_HZ_MAX = 96000;
```

Also I know that there is support for 192kHz in few Android music players like PowerAmp, so how did they achieve it?

Comment: they use native (c++) code to achieve this. Not Android SDK code

Comment: @metalurgus is there any native lib for that?

Comment: I think FFMPEG should do the trick, but I always found it too complex for me to use it.

Comment: According to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2312542/android-play-raw-audio-from-c-side NDK can't play audio.

Comment: Do you really think so? You think it can play video, but can't do audio?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81636/discussion-between-czajna666-and-metalurgus).

Comment: Allegedly would likely be the word. There's no point in spending the power  budget on achieving a SNR better than the analogue audio output can support, for it to then be consumed on a pair ear-buds anyway.   It's safe to assume that the only requirement for audio codecs in most phones is that they're cheap.